# prediccion regresion lineal python, sklearn

Tags: python, inteligencia-artificial, regresión-lineal

tengo un coidgo que realiza una regresion lineal simple a los datos de un csv de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me muestra la prediccion, lo que quiesiera hacer es poderle dar un valor futuro para que calcule la prediccion hasta ese dia, por ejemplo quiero saber el valor de la prediccion en el dia 50.

este es mi codigo:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset = pd.read_csv('datosdelared2.csv',sep=';')
x = dataset.iloc[:, :1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,1].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size 0.25)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_preds = lr.predict(x_test)
comp=pd.DataFrame({'real':y_test,'pred':y_preds })
#metrica error cuadratico medio
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
MSE=mean_squared_error(y_test,y_preds)
eje_x=list(range(x_test.shape[0]))
eje_y=y_test
eje_y2=y_preds
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(eje_x,eje_y,'-',eje_x,eje_y2,'-')
fig.set_size_inches(15,8)
#Ridge's Regression
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
ridge=Ridge(alpha=1)
ridge.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_preds=ridge.predict(x_test)
print(mean_squared_error(y_test,y_preds))
alphas=np.arange(0.01,2,0.0001)
len(alphas)
mse=list()
for alpha in alphas:
ridge=Ridge(alpha=alpha)
ridge.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_preds=ridge.predict(x_test)
error=round(mean_squared_error(y_test,y_preds),3)
mse.append(error)

alpha_error=pd.DataFrame({'mse':mse,'alpha':alphas })
alpha_error[alpha_error['mse']==alpha_error['mse'].min()]
ridge=Ridge(alpha=1)
ridge.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_preds=ridge.predict(x_test)
print(mean_squared_error(y_test,y_preds))
comparacion=pd.DataFrame({'real':x_test,'pred':y_preds })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenid@ a la comunidad.

Dado que mantienes una referencia a los regresores `lr = LinearRegression()` y `ridge=Ridge(alpha=1)`, luego de entrenarlo mediante el metodo `.fit(x_train,y_train)`, puedes hacer una predicción mediante el método `.predict(x)`.

Esto se puede lograr de la siguiente manera:

```
# creas el arreglo con los días que quieres predecir, en este caso del 1 al 50
x = np.arange(1, 51, 1)

# formatear el input como lo espera el .predict: (#_elementos, #_caracteristicas)
x = x.reshape(-1, 1)  # reshape: (50, ) -> (50, 1)

# haces la prediccion basado en el modelo entrenado o 'fiteado'
y_lr = lr.predict(x) 
y_ridge = ridge.predict(x)

# prediccion desde el día 1 hasta el día 50 queda en y_lr e y_ridge
print(y_lr.shape)  # (50, 1)  # prediccion a 50 dias
```

Comment: lo intente pero me da el siguiente error:ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
 49 50].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: Ahi lo arreglé @señora confirmame si esta OK

Comment: que pena, es que no puedo predecir a partir de y_preds que son los datos de prediccion

Comment: solo me predice a partir de y_ridge

Comment: No se podría predecir a partir de `y_preds` dado que esa variable contiene sólo predicciones de `x_test`, que es un arreglo de valores entre 1 y 12; no es un modelo es solo un arreglo. Las predicciones se hacen sobre los objetos/modelos `lr` y `ridge`. Espero poder ayudarte, por lo que intenta dar más información acerca de los problemas que estas teniendo.- Si resolví tu pregunta, recuerda seleccionarla como respuesta correcta.

Comment: Hola, he modificado mi codigo ahora con redes neuronales pero no he podido modificar el rango, me podrias ayudar?

Comment: seguro cuentame mas detalles

Comment: como es tan larga te envio el link donde se encuentra mas detallada https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/316567/error-when-checking-input-expected-lstm-37-input-to-have-3-dimensions-but-got