# Error when checking input: expected lstm_37_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (0, 1)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, predicción

Estoy intentando realizar una predicción de un *dataset* que consta de dos campos, la fecha dd/mm/yyyy en la columna *Date* y un valor numérico 400.3 mediante **lstm keras** pero tengo el siguiente error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: Error when checking input: expected lstm_37_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (0, 1)

Cuando intento escoger el número de días en los que quiero realizar mi predicción: por ejemplo, si mi set de datos va hasta el día de hoy, quiero realizar mi predicciín 50 días después u 80 días después.

El código es el siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(4)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM,Flatten


Funciones auxiliares

def graficar_predicciones(real, prediccion):
 plt.plot(real[0:len(prediccion)],color='red', label='Valor real de la 
 acción')
plt.plot(prediccion, color='blue', label='Predicción de la acción')
plt.ylim(1.1 * np.min(prediccion)/2, 1.1 * np.max(prediccion))
plt.xlabel('Tiempo')
plt.ylabel('Valor de la acción')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


Lectura de los datos

dataset = pd.read_csv('AAPL_2006-01-01_to_2018-01-01.csv', index_col='Date', 
parse_dates=['Date'])
dataset.head()


Sets de entrenamiento y validación 
La LSTM se entrenará con datos de 2016 hacia atrás. La validación se hará 
con datos de 2017 en adelante.
En ambos casos sólo se usará el valor más alto de la acción para cada día

set_entrenamiento = dataset[:'2018'].iloc[:,1:2]
set_validacion = dataset['2019':].iloc[:,1:2]

set_entrenamiento['High'].plot(legend=True)
set_validacion['High'].plot(legend=True)
plt.legend(['Entrenamiento (2006-2016)', 'Validación (2017)'])
plt.show()

# Normalización del set de entrenamiento
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
set_entrenamiento_escalado = sc.fit_transform(set_entrenamiento)

# La red LSTM tendrá como entrada "time_step" datos consecutivos, y como 
salida 1 dato (la predicción a
# partir de esos "time_step" datos). Se conformará de esta forma el set de 
entrenamiento
time_step = 60
X_train = []
Y_train = []
m = len(set_entrenamiento_escalado)

for i in range(time_step,m):
# X: bloques de "time_step" datos: 0-time_step, 1-time_step+1, 2- 
time_step+2, etc
X_train.append(set_entrenamiento_escalado[i-time_step:i,0])

# Y: el siguiente dato
Y_train.append(set_entrenamiento_escalado[i,0])
X_train, Y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(Y_train)

# Reshape X_train para que se ajuste al modelo en Keras
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))


# Red LSTM

dim_entrada = (X_train.shape[1],1)
dim_salida = 1
na = 50

modelo = Sequential()
modelo.add(LSTM(units=na, input_shape=dim_entrada))
modelo.add(Dense(units=dim_salida))
modelo.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
modelo.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=20,batch_size=32)

# Validación (predicción del valor de las acciones)

x_test = set_validacion.values
x_test = sc.transform(x_test)

X_test = []
for i in range(time_step,len(x_test)):
  X_test.append(x_test[i-time_step:i,0])  
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],1))
x = np.arange(50,1,1)
x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
prediccion = modelo.predict(x)
prediccion = sc.inverse_transform(prediccion)
```

Comment: Los modulos recurrentes como lstm esperan una entrada de 3 dimensiones (N, L, F) donde N es la cantidad de muestras del batch, L es el largo de la secuencia que representa cada muestra (por ejemplo, si una muestra es un libro, L puede ser la cantidad de caracteres o de palabras del libro), y F representa la dimensionalidad del vector de características de cada elemento de la secuencia (Por ejemplo, en texto se suele usar un word-vector para cada palabra de dimension 500, o si cada elemento es un carácter puede ser su codificación en ASCII).

Comment: Entonces por ejemplo, para texto podemos tener un input size de (32, 100, 500) donde tenemos 32 noticias de 100 palabras donde cada palabra tiene un vector de características de largo 500. Notemos que este input usualmente contiene solo números (floats). Si entiendes esto entonces vas bien solo tienes que llevar tus datos a esta forma.

Comment: Debo notar que lograr diseñar y modelar los datos para introducirlos a la red es la parte difícil (si no es la única parte) de usar estas técnicas de Machine Learning. en este sentido me parece un poco amplia la pregunta pues la respuesta ideal a ella resultaría en el código prácticamente listo para echarlo a andar y en eso no te puedo ayudar mucho pues no es nada trivial. Pero si logramos desglosarla felizmente te ayudo como hasta ahora.